# date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. ou are *required* to use the date.timezone setting

Tags: datetime, symfony

I've just installed Symfony3, and apparently my "date.timezone" in php.ini was not good. So I found php.ini doing : phpinfo() in app.php, and I watched "Loaded Configuration File" to see where I could find the php.ini file.

I change the value to "Europe/Paris", I saved and restart MAMP, but nothing. 
Always the same message : 
"Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone
  _set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC
  ' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone."

Actually I'm just trying to run "php bin/console server:run" ..

So if some of you have an idea :)

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly configure your `php.ini` for your Apacher server.

But `php bin/console server:run` is not using the same `php.ini` file.

Try to launch `php --ini` to locate it.

Here is mine:

```
php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\dev\bin\php\php-5.6.28\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Comment: Sorry for the response time, ok I'll try it tonight :)